# hibernate query builder for lucene time range

Tags: lucene, queryover

I am building a lucene query for an indexed object to determine if current time lies between the range of start Time and end Time. I'm unable to get the exact lucene query .

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery5=queryBuilder3.bool()
    .must(queryBuilder3.keyword().onFields("TimeDependentProfileKey").matching("TimeKey").createQuery())
    .must(queryBuilder3.range().onField("StartTime").above(new Time(0)).createQuery())
    .must(queryBuilder3.range().onField("StopTime").below(new Time(0)).createQuery()).createQuery();`
```

The lucene query which was generated looks like:

```
+TimeDependentProfileKey:3 +StartTime:[19700101000000000 TO *] +StopTime:[* TO 19700101000000000]
```

how do i change the format of timestamp, can anyone please help me.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem.  What do you mean, change the format of the timestamp?  Hibernate/Lucene should handle formatting the date for querying, assuming you are using a field with an `@DateBridge` annotation.  What is the problem you are observing?

Comment: @femtoRgon: thanks for the reply :)The starttime in lucene query is showed in a different format, for which the format present in object is not matching

Comment: A different format than what?  Point is, your query looks correct.  Do you have your `above`/`below` backwards?  "starttime after x and stoptime before x" sounds like nonsense, though not sure how that really reflects your actual query.  Otherwise, there is probably something wrong with how you are indexing your data.

Comment: The value in the field "StartTime" and "StopTime" are stored in the format(HH:mm:ss), while building a lucene query for Range the TimeStamp is not in the desired format[HH:mm:ss], I even tried using the simpleDateFormatter for the time oject parameter in above() and below()

Answer (score 0):

By searching for a date object, you are deferring formatting to hibernate.  I would consider the format you specified as functional, though perhaps not ideal.  If you want to use your own formatting, you must deal in strings, be consistent in your formatting, and make sure your format will work well for sorting and range queries as a string.

If you want to have hibernate handle formatting dates for you, you need to define your date field with a [`@DateBridge(resolution = ...)` annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5162).  This ensures that hibernate will format dates effective for correct range querying and sorting in lucene, and allows you to query against the field with date objects instead of strings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i tried using @DateBridge(resolution=RESOLUTION.SECOND) but with this, i could get a format of YYYYmmddhhmmss, but since i wanted only hhmmss , i converted the date object to a integer and then queried the integer field to get the desired result.   Thanks for your guidance. :)